# how to get properly encoded accented characters?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am experiencing unexpected behavior. When saving a record in the database and when getting the created record. I observe that the characters with an accent are erroneously encoded. When verifying the database using `datagrip`, I observe that the value of the affected field is properly encoded. But if I check with the mysql client I see that the values ​​are badly encoded

In the object obtained after saving the value of the affected field looks like this

```
S\u00f3ni
```

In `datagrip` I get

```
Soni
```

In mysql client I get

```
S�ni
```

When verifying the encoding of the table with the command `show table status where name like 'table_name'` I get the value `utf8_general_ci` in the `Collation` column

When executing the statement `show create table table_name;` I observe the following

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Finally in `php.ini` I get the following

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

**update 0**

The database collation

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name = "dbname";

+----------------------------+
| default_character_set_name |
+----------------------------+
| latin1                     |
+----------------------------+
```

How do I get the characters to be properly encoded?

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Use UTF-8 consequently _everywhere_. In your mysql client, run these 3 commands: `SET character_set_client='UTF8'; SET character_set_results='UTF8'; SET character_set_connection='UTF8';` which will set the client and the transport to utf-8

Comment: [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) and [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/).

Comment: See also "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored